# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First approach to create many-to-many relation

Tags: c#, silverlight, many-to-many, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I'm using the Silverlight 5 Beta SDK and the EntityFramework 4.1 in an Silverlight Application.

I'll try to create the two tables 'Author' and 'Book'. In SQL, there should be a third (join) table, which makes the many-to-many relation between Author and Book (one author could have written many books and a book could be written from many authors).

This is what I've got so far:

```
namespace CodeFirst.Models.Web
{    
    public class Author
    {
        public Author()
        {
            this.Books = new HashSet<Book>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }


    public class Book
    {
        public Book()
        {
            this.Authors = new HashSet<Author>();
        }


        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    }


    // Should I do something like that:
    public class AuthorMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Author>
    {
        public AuthorMapping() : base()
        {   
            //this.HasMany (g => g.Books)
            //    .WithMany(m => m.Authors)
            //    .Map     (gm => gm.ToTable    ("Author_Book")
            //                      .MapLeftKey ("AuthorID")
            //                      .MapRightKey("BookID"));
        }
    }


    public class CodeFirstModelContext : DbContext
    {
        public CodeFirstModelContext() : base()
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @".\MSSQLSERVER2008;Database=CodeFirst;Trusted_Connection=true;";
        }


        public DbSet<Author> Authors  { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Book>   Books { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AuthorMapping());

            // tell Code First to ignore PluralizingTableName convention
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }


    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class CodeFirstDomainService : DomainService
    {
        public CodeFirstDomainService()
        {
            this.m_modelContext = new CodeFirstModelContext();
        }


        public IQueryable<Author> GetAuthors()
        {
            return this.m_modelContext.Authors;//.Include("Books");
        }

        public void InsertAuthor(Author Author)
        {
            this.m_modelContext.Insert(Author);
        }

        public void UpdateAuthor(Author Author)
        {
            this.m_modelContext.Update(Author, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(Author));
        }

        public void DeleteAuthor(Author Author)
        {
            this.m_modelContext.Delete(Author);
        }


        public IQueryable<Book> GetBooks()
        {
            return this.m_modelContext.Books;//.Include("Authors");
        }

        public void InsertBook(Book Author)
        {
            this.m_modelContext.Insert(Author);
        }

        public void UpdateBook(Book Author)
        {
            this.m_modelContext.Update(Author, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(Author));
        }

        public void DeleteBook(Book Author)
        {
            this.m_modelContext.Delete(Author);
        }


        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
                this.m_modelContext.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        protected override bool PersistChangeSet()
        {
            this.m_modelContext.SaveChanges();
            return base.PersistChangeSet();
        }


        private CodeFirstModelContext m_modelContext;
    }
}
```

The most obvious problem is, that the navigation properties (Books in Author and Authors in Book) aren't created from the code designer in my client project.

What do I need to do?

**EDIT:**
Okay, now I'm able to use only one of the NavigationProperties simultaneously. If I try to 'Include' both I'm getting the following error:

```
Association 'Author_Book' defined on entity type 'CodeFirst.Models.Web.Author' is invalid. It is a foreign key association but the property type is not a singleton.
```

This is my updated code:

```
public class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        this.Books = new Collection<Book>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(32)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Association("Author_Book", "ID", "ID")]
    [Include]
    public Collection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}


public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        this.Authors = new Collection<Author>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(32)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Association("Author_Book", "ID", "ID")]
    [Include]
    public Collection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}


public class AuthorMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Author>
{
    public AuthorMapping() : base()
    {
        this.HasMany (g => g.Books)
            .WithMany(m => m.Authors)
            .Map     (gm => gm.ToTable("Author_Book"));
    }
}

public class BookMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public BookMapping() : base()
    {
        this.HasMany (m => m.Authors)
            .WithMany(g => g.Books)
            .Map     (gm => gm.ToTable("Author_Book"));
    }
}
```

It seems to me, that Entity Framework still isn't able to deal with many-to-many relations. At least, that's what the error message implies.

**EDIT2:**
I've changed my code after I've read [this post on social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d894c8af-5985-4995-88e2-c8733e4a51ea):

```
public class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        this.Books = new Collection<Book>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(32)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Association("Author_Book", "Book_ID", "Author_ID")]
    [Include]
    [ForeignKey("Book_ID")]
    public Collection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public int Book_ID { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        this.Authors = new Collection<Author>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(32)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Association("Author_Book", "Author_ID", "Book_ID")]
    [Include]
    [ForeignKey("Author_ID")]
    public Collection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public int Author_ID { get; set; }
}
```

It doesn't fixed my problem. The same error is still present. I've tested to remove the AssociationAttribute without success. Am I doing somethinf wrong here?

Comment: @Caglar Gonul: Thanks for your answer, but I can not see how this refers to my issue. I'm not expanding or mapping a existing database or table. I'm using 'Code First' to create the table from code by the Entity Framework.

Comment: >code designer in my client project. What? Are you using WCF? Can you show us tables, that are generated by this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think problem here lies in the WCF RIA service, not anything EF related. That is, that WCF doesn't like interfaces. Solution would be use `Collection` instead of `ICollection`. I'm sure EF won't mind it and it will fix your WCF problem.

**Edit**: This may solve your problem http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d894c8af-5985-4995-88e2-c8733e4a51ea

Comment: +1 | Yes, it worked. Unfortunately, this is very unclear and almost undocumented. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting an other error. I've edited my initial post.

Comment: I think you should open new question with only new problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961672/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-approach-to-realize-many-to-many-relation-over-do